# Download file with .pdf extension inside an webView

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview

I have few local html files inside and assets folder that contain pdf files available for download to users. But I'm not been able to download files inside webView.  I searched whole google and best I came up with

```
  webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));

            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Name of your downloadble file goes here, example: Mathematics II ");
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

But still when I clicked the link it shows Dowanloading and then on Notification's panel It shows Can't Dowanload Error.

and my manifest.xml file is

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I'm using simulator Bluestacks to Test my App.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you downloading a file from a https site or local?

Comment: @Steven I am download file from google drive. For example, one link is https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B2j3ckof7nFGM3FHeDhKemd5YTg

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Does your app crashes?

Comment: no it doesn't crashes and when I view inside the Download folder, The file is there and has been sucessfully downloaded. Problem is the download progress bar won't be visible. So for users, it is impossible to keep track of how much download is left or whether is file is actually downloading or not as there is no any download bar appears in notificatons panel, it only is visible when you exit the app and if you go inside download folder, file is right there.

Comment: Okey why do you say then " It shows Can't Dowanload Error."